# RPM spec file - Is it possible to dynamically populate a spec file variable

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I have a spec file. I need to %define a spec variable that gets its value from a one line file on the system.

For example

```
%define path `cat /home/user/path_file`
```

and in path_file is one line

```
/var/www/html/hosts
```

This partially works. I say that begins in the RPM BUILD output sometimes the value of `${path}` is literally my command `cat /home/user/path_file` and sometimes the value is the line in the path_file (/var/www/html/hosts) as it should be?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can define rpmbuild variables with `%(cmd)` at the top of the spec file. Notice the command is in parenthesis, not curly brackets. An example:

```
%define whoami %(whoami)
```

And elsewhere in the spec file, such as a script or the build/install sections, use the variable as normal in the curly brackets like this:

```
echo "The user that built this is %{whoami}"
```

The `cmd` can be anything, including your cat command. Be careful - when another user rebuilds the spec file it may not find the file. So it'll be preferable to use the %{sourcedir} macro like this:

```
%define path %(cat %{sourcedir}/path_file)
```

And make sure that `path_file` is in the source directory and included as a source in the spec file.

Comment: Corey - if I want /home/user/path_file to be "Required" for the rpm to run? Can I make it a PreReq or Required parameter in my spec file? When I try required it says the file is not there  and it totally is there?

Comment: The PreReq, etc options for depending on files being installed on the system actually look in the rpm database for the existence of a package that own the file. It doesn't check the filesystem for the existence of the file.

Comment: @last_shogun There are ways outside of prereq, etc though, such as having a %pre script that checks for the existence of the file, and if not there, echos an error message and exits with a non-zero status.