# RPM Spec File Macro Expansion

Tags: rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am building a kernel module and will need to provide a version for each minor release of the distro. I plan to follow the release naming convention of `.elX_Y` to designate the major version X and minor Y for the rpm. I am trying to use the following but do not understand why the macro does not seem to get properly defined and/or expanded.

```
# The macro in question, should evaluate to the minor rev
%define minor     %(grep -oP '.*8\.\K([0-9]+)' /etc/redhat-release | tr -d '\n')

# Package meta
<other fields>
Release:        3%{?dist}_%{minor}
```

But when this is run, `%{minor}` expands to nothing. The resulting package is simply named with `.el8_.x86_64` rather than the expected `.el8_5.x86_64` (showing minor rev 5). I tried replacing `%define` with `%global` but that still did not work.

I have confirmed the expansion of the grep command itself works fine in the `%pre` section but `%{minor}` is still empty.

```
%pre
# Successfully prints 5 on my install
echo %(grep -oP '.*8\.\K([0-9]+)' /etc/redhat-release | tr -d '\n')

# Prints empty new line
echo %{minor}
```

The only success I've had is to use the command directly in the `Release` tag. The package built is then named `<name-version>.el8_5.x86_64.rpm` as expected.

```
# Package meta
<other fields>
Release:        3%{?dist}_%(grep -oP '.*8\.\K([0-9]+)' /etc/redhat-release | tr -d '\n')
```

While I have an acceptable workaround, I would like to be able to use the `minor` macro in other parts of the spec file. Why is the macro define not working as I expect?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33771728/define-version-with-script-in-rpm-spec-file), the command to get the minor version might not be working correctly in rpmbuild %define statement.

Below commands seems to work for me.

```
%define minor       %(grep -o '8\.[0-9.]*' /etc/redhat-release |  cut -d '.' -f2)
OR
%define minor       %(awk '{ print $4 }' /etc/redhat-release | cut -d '.' -f2)
```

EDIT 1:

It seems that your command can also work with a minor tweak. i.e., escape the slash before K by adding an extra slash.

```
%define minor       %(grep -oP '.*8\.\\K([0-9]+)' /etc/redhat-release | tr -d '\n')
```